¿Como puedo insertar datos de un formulario e insertarlo en mysql?
Estoy intentando automatizar la gestión de usuarios de una web. La web esta en constante crecimiento y tiene varios subsitíos donde acceder según los permisos que contenga el usuario.
Tengo una tabla donde se almacenan los datos de los subsitíos. La idea es que al crear un nuevo subsitió y agregar la fila en la tabla de la BD.
En la web se agrega automáticamente esa fila con un foreach. En la gestión de usuarios y permisos, aparece el nuevo subsitió, va perfecto. Utilizo este código:
$query = '
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column_name SEPARATOR \', \')
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  where TABLE_SCHEMA = \'ac_nqn\'
    and TABLE_NAME = \'usuarios\'
';

$resultado = mysqli_query( $conn, $query );

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultado )){

  $datos = $fila[0];
  $array_datos=explode(",",$datos);

Y acomodo todo en checkbox para asignar a los usuarios donde van a acceder. Por ejemplo usuario "pepe" sera asignado al checkbox con nombre "index-1". El index-1 es el nombre del subsitio y trae ese nombre de la fila de la BD.
$contador = 0;
foreach ($array_datos as $val_1){
  if($contador > 3 ){
    echo '<td class="td_checkbox">
      <label>' . $val_1 . '</label>
      <input type="checkbox" style="cursor:not-allowed;"
        onclick="return false;" id="settings-' . $contador . '"
        class="settings" name="CHECK' . $val_1 . '" value="">
      </td>';
  }
  $contador ++;
} 

Pido disculpas, se que soy muy malo expresando y tratando de explicar. Estaré atento a comentarios para poder aclarar las dudas.
Toda esta parte funciona de maravilla. El tema esta que cuando quiero crear un nuevo usuario, y asignarle un subsitio, no se como mandar los datos del nuevo usuario a la tabla de usuarios, donde envio

El nombre de usuario
El tipo de permiso
El subsitió asignado.

Aca es donde se me complica por no entender como desarrollarlo.
Como recibo los POST de los checkbox de manera dinámica? Porque al crear un nuevo subsitió y agregarlo en la pantalla de gestión de usuarios, se crea un nuevo checkbox para enviar en el POST, pero no se como recibirlo de manera dinámica (ósea no tener que volver al código)
un ejemplo de como recibo los checkbox
$check_NOC = (isset($_POST['CHECKN NOC'])) ? '1' : '0';

Y luego estaria el tema de insertar los datos, asi lo tengo ahora
foreach($datos as $insert_valores){
  if (
    $stmt = $conn->prepare(
      "INSERT INTO usuarios ($insert_valores)
       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    )
  ){
  $stmt->bind_param(
    "isssssssssssss", $id, $permisos, $usuario, $nomYape,
    $check_NOC, $check_RDLS, $check_PH, $check_RIO, $check_AND,
    $check_BARROSA, $check_EFO, $check_LLL,
    $check_PLARENAS, $check_TEX
  );
  $stmt->execute();
  }
}

Pero me tira error al agregar el foreach. $datos -> contiene las columnas de la tabla
El error es:

el argumento foreach() debe ser de tipo matriz|objeto

Mi idea es automatizar todo, sin tener que volver al código para agregar una nueva variable. Si alguien pudiera guiarme para poder realizarlo, agradeceré muchísimo!

$datos no es un array en el contexto del error. ¿Cómo creas esa variable? Luego, la pregunta no es demasiado clara. Te recomendaría que uses Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript para actualizar los nuevos valores en el cliente una vez creados.

no mostré, pero utilizo $datos porque contiene el los nombres de las columnas con una , cosa que $array_datos que utilizo en otra parte, les quita las comas

Se que es complicado de entender, no soy bueno explicando.. el tema que ajax o javascript no lo tengo claro. Estoy mas con php

pero si es complicado de hacerlo, buscare algo con JS

Se trata de usar la herramienta más adecuada de acuerdo a lo que quieras hacer. No parece ser un asunto demasiado complicado. ¿De dónde sale $datos? El mensaje de error te está diciendo que $datos no es un array.  Si estamos hablando de esta variable $datos = $fila[0];, lo que estás haciendo en tu código es meter en $datos el valor de la primera columna del SELECT. Además, quedará solamente el valor de la última fila recorrida en el while. Aquí el problema principal es que no estás explicando el problema. No se entiende con claridad lo que quieres hacer con esos datos.

es mala practica usar espacios en los nombres ... $_POST['CHECKN NOC'] esto puede traer problemas ... digo yo .. IMHO
